# Javaw still creates a console window; Why is this?

Tags: java, console, jython, javaw

My game engine's a combination of Jython and Java so I'm executing a jar along with a python script instead of a classfile.

```
java -jar Jython.jar init.py
```

However, when I change "java" to "javaw" it does not hide the console like it normally would. Why is this and is there a way to work around it?

Comment: Just a guess: is your `java`/`javaw` command line in a batch file that is itself responsible for the console?

Comment: Well it is running off a batch file, but that's my only method of executing the code, so if that's why it wont work then I'll just stick to it.

Comment: I just tested it off cmd instead of a batch file and the problem persists.  Ideas?

Comment: Could you try creating a shortcut (I'm assuming you're running on Windows since you mentioned batch file) that executes javaw directly with the parameters needed to run your game engine?

Comment: I just attempted it and not only did it create a command window, but it also gave me an error that it couldn't access Jython.jar

Comment: is [this link](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) helpful?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the JavaConsole is a function of java.exe vs javaw.exe.  The difference is java.exe has stdout & stderr write to the SystemConsole and javaw.exe runs without stdout and stderr writting to the SystemConsole.  Running java.exe will block because it is connected to the SystemConsole. Running javaw.exe will return control to the launching SystemConsole (or script) and continue to run without a SystemConsole.

Disable the JavaConsole using the java control panel or the java icon on the task bar.

[image: from the java control panel]

[image: from the task bar java icon]